# Fix a regex that extract twitter id from a twitter url

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a bug in my wysiwyg editor.
I have a box where I past a tweet url, and I must extract the ID to replace it with the embed code.

```
regex: {
        twitter: /https?:\/\/twitter.com\/[a-zA-Z_]{1,20}\/status\/([0-9]*)/
    }

if (str.match(this.opts.regex.twitter)) {
  parsed = str.replace(this.opts.regex.twitter, '<blockquote class="twitter-tweet tw-align-center"><a href="https://twitter.com/x/status/$1">TWEET $1</a></blockquote>');
  return parsed;
   }
```

The bug is in my regex

```
 /https?:\/\/twitter.com\/[a-zA-Z_]{1,20}\/status\/([0-9]*)/
```

If I take this url

```
https://twitter.com/howard3141/status/1330546000969273347
```

It doesn't work because 'howard3141' has some numbers inside.

Comment: Please explain what constitutes a legal twitter username. Why not match anything up to the next slash? `[^/]+` instead of `[a-zA-Z_]{1,20}`. If you just want to handle numbers, add `\d`.

Comment: `/https?:\/\/twitter.com\/[0-9a-zA-Z_]{1,20}\/status\/([0-9]*)/` add digit to your username expression as `[0-9a-zA-Z_]`.

Comment: Why not use `location.pathName.match(/\/(.*)\//)[1]`

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to fetch from a URL, `window.location` provides great apis to get value.

Following is the demonstration of it.

Note: I'm using [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) to create a location like object, but it should work with `window.location` as well

```js
var url = new URL('', 'https://twitter.com/howard3141/status/1330546000969273347')

console.log(url.pathname.match(/\/([^\/]*)\//)[1])
```